# GAE - Python equivalent of getRemainingMillis()

Tags: python, google-app-engine

As described in the article about [dealing with DeadlineExceededError](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors) GAE-Java has a way (`ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getRemainingMillis()`) for getting the remaining time before the request deadline is reached, which can be different depending on whether the handler was called from a browser or as a task.

Is there an equivalent in GAE-Python, other than keeping track using my own timer and having my handler be aware if it's running as a task or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that anything available as a method call would be available in their development system to facilitate offline development, there's no record of anything close in their 1.8.3 Python library. The apiproxy code making RPC calls appears to just set/use plain old socket timers, which doesn't appear to have a "how much longer until my timeout hits" method of any sort.

Looks like you might be on your own to implement such a check, but would be an awesome feature request to make to Google, I'd vote it up myself: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/

Comment: It's already been [done in 2011](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4600) and I've now voted for it. Your turn :)